# Angular - function is called recursively from html

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular2-observables

I am having difficulty loading an image, the method `getUserProfileImage()` get triggered multiple times, is there a way to make method call only once within loop. I know it is result of angular's change detection strategy, but how to overcome this issue?

I have been looking into it for a while and there are few questions addressing the same issue through various hacks but I don't want to hack and stop change detection strategy.

```
    <div *ngFor="let user of listOfContacts">
            <img class="rounded profile-thumbnail ptr" [src]="getUserProfileImage(user.UserName, user.UserId)" id="image-id-{{user.UserId}}" [routerLink]="['/community/userProfile', '0', user.UserId]">
    </div>
```

**getUserProfileImage()** method inside **____.ts** class

```
    getUserProfileImage(userName: string, itemId: number){

      let loadImageSub = this.util.getUserProfileImageByUserName(userName).subscribe(contactsObj => {

      let imageUrl = this.toUrl(contactsObj["Images"][0].SrcAttr);
      console.log("contact profile image", imageUrl);
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("image-id-" + itemId)).src = imageUrl;
      loadImageSub.unsubscribe();

    });
 }
```

**Error**
same image being loaded multiple times, function is called recursively.
[image]

Comment: Don't call function from HTML, get image src with ngOnInit or other event and use it

Comment: Instead of just mentioning that calling functions from the template isn't exactly ideal, I'll refer you to a decent article explaining the issue in detail (see [link](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)). Sometimes it's not really possible or difficult to avoid function calls, mind.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the logic and now loading images from ngOnInit and then displaying them in html. @yogendarji

Answer (score 1):

don't call functions in templates whenever you can, as you also yourself already established. Sounds to me that you would want to fetch all data before even displaying the template, so that you would have a nice structured data and the image in a property in each object which you can display in ngFor.

If you are getting your contacts from an api call, you could add use of `forkJoin` and `switchMap` to get the url of the image for each object. Here is a sample of fetching all users, then we fetch all posts that a user has posted and store it in a `posts` property in the original users data. Please apply to your usecase. You could even use `async` pipe and assign all to a observable instead, but lets go with subscribe here. Also avoid `any` usage, I'm just being lazy here...

```
// get all users here first!
this.getUsers()
  .pipe(
    switchMap((data: any) => {
      // ok, now for each user, make a call to get their posts, return the posts and the original user data
      return forkJoin(
        data.map((y: any) =>
          this.getPosts(y.id).pipe(map((data) => ({ ...y, posts: data })))
        )
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

So in your case you would want to call inside switchMap forkjoin on all the contact person images, attach that to a property in your contact object instead of `posts` here in my sample :)

Comment: Thanks much appreciated, I changed the logic to load images from ngOnInit and not html. But this is helpful way and definitely will look into it. Thanks for your input.