# how to check if a method api call is finished and then go to next step in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two methods in both I am doing api calls. Method one is calling out method 2 and should continue with its process after method 2 api call is finished. I tried to do this with the complete function inside subscription, but I am having the problem that method 2 is contiinuing doing its own work without waiting for method 2 to finish. Can someone tell me where my mistake is?

```
 getPerson() {
    this.setSelectedFlag() --> Whenever this finishes continue with method
    this.personArray = this.form.controls.person.value;
    this.personArray .forEach((id) => {
      if (!this.personMap.has(id)) {
        this.loading.start();
        this.api.getpersonsData({
          id,
        }).subscribe((response) => {
          this.personMap.set(id, response);
          this.loading.stop();
        });
      }
    });
    this.personMap.forEach((person, id) => {
      if (!this.personArray.includes(id)) {
        this.personen.delete(id);
      }
    });
  }

  setSelectedFlag() {
    this.personArray = this.form.controls.person.value;
    this.personArray.forEach((id) => {
      if (!this.setFlagForPerson.has(id)) {
        this.personArraySaving.ids.push(id);
        this.api.setSelectedForPerson({
          body: this.personArraySaving,
        }).subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            console.log(data);
          },
          complete: () => {
            return --> I thought this would signal its finish
          },
        });
      }
      });
    
  }
```

Comment: I would use a `switchMap` and `forkJoin` for this. Not a duplicate question, as the requirements are different, but to showcase what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70124221/angular-function-is-called-recursively-from-html/70124686#70124686

Answer (score 0):

Using promises would allow you to let setSelectedFlag() return a promise. After it returns you can continue with the code in getPerson()

```
getPerson() {
 this.setSelectedFlag().then(() => {
      // rest of the code.
 })
}


setSelectedFlag(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
            ....
           complete: () => {
             resolve();
           }
    })
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise